# React/Next JS - How to update data in a table component using data from different js files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building a resource library using React/Next JS ----> [resource library screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmCwY.png)

I have categories at the top (**design, code, tools, etc**) and each `category` will be using the same `table` component. Each `category` has its own js file with data and the idea is that the data in the `table` component will update depending on which category the user clicks. Right now data inside the table is coming from the `designData.js` file, but I want to update the data based on the category that the user clicked (ex: if user clicks on `Tools` category, I want the table to show the data inside `toolsData.js`).

What is the best way to update the data in the table so that it uses the right data.js file?(props? state? componentDidMount? something else?).

This is a sample of my structure (I don't mind if I need to redo what I have so I am open to suggestions.)

```
components/
  |-table.js
  |-categories.js  
data/
  |-designData.js
  |-codeData.js
  |-toolsData.js
pages/
  |- library/
  |     |-design.js
  |     |-code.js
  |     |-tools.js
  |- _app.js
  |-index.js
```